# Wrong inequality check in numpy.arange()

Tags: python, numpy

## Question

Suppose that

```
quarters = numpy.arange(start=1947, stop=2017,       step=1/4 )
months   = numpy.arange(start=1947, stop=2016+10/12, step=1/12)
```

Why does this

```
months[3] < quarters[1]  # True
```

happen?
And how do I avoid it?

---

## Context

I am working with some economic data and I need to interpolate a quarterly time series, so to artificially get monthly data.
In the code that follows I assume:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as ip
```

So I go ahead and define the time-domain of my data:

```
quarters = np.arange(start=1947, stop=2017,       step=1/4 )
months   = np.arange(start=1947, stop=2016+10/12, step=1/12)
```

The original quarterly time series indeed runs from the first quarter of 1947 (labeled as "1947-1-1" in yyyy-m-d format) to the last quarter of 2016 (labeled as "2016-10-1").
A quick check confirms that the two domains coincide, so that `months` is simply "denser" than `quarters`:

```
np.min(quarters) == np.min(months)  # True
np.max(quarters) == np.max(months)  # True
```

Then I move to the real thing.
I import one time series, call it `gdp` by using `np.genfromtxt()` and I make sure I've got it right, so that

```
gdp.shape == quarters.shape  # True
```

I am interested in the first difference of such data:

```
dgdp = np.diff(gdp)
dgdp = np.concatenate(([np.nan], dpgdp))  # needed for consistency with the time-domain
```

and I want to interpolate the monthly first difference:

```
interp_df = ip.interp1d(quarters[1:], dgdp[1:])
```

This works just fine and `interp_df` is indeed the intended class that should be returned by `ip.interp1d()`.

However, as soon as I try to get the interpolated data

```
dgdp_mon = interp_df(months[3:])
```

Scipy complains with `ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range`.
By debugging and inspecting Scipy's source code, it turns out that the problem lies in the inequality checks in the method `_check_bounds(self, x_new)` within the submodule `interpolate.py`, and this essentially goes back to the **question** above.

Comment: `np.allclose(months[:30:3], quarters[:10])` is True

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy.linspace instead:

```
quarters = numpy.linspace(start=1947, stop=2017, endpoint=False,num=(2017-1947)*4)
months   = numpy.linspace(start=1947, stop=2016+10./12, endpoint=False, num=(2016 - 1947)*12 + 10)
```

According to [numpy.arange documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not
>   be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by floating point rounding errors. Generate your data as integers, then calculate the values you want.

```
import numpy

quarters = numpy.arange(start=1947, stop=2017,       step=1/4 )
months   = numpy.arange(start=1947, stop=2016+10/12, step=1/12)

print([months[3], quarters[1]])
print(months[3] < quarters[1])
# [1947.2499999999998, 1947.25]
# True


quarters = numpy.arange(start=1947*4,  stop=2017*4,       step=1)/4
months   = numpy.arange(start=1947*12, stop=2016*12 + 10, step=1)/12

print([months[3], quarters[1]])
print(months[3] < quarters[1])
# [1947.25, 1947.25]
# False
```